# How to make 8 identical things appear on a form if i select 8 in my select list?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code, easier to understand if you played Quake III Arena.

```
<select id="playerlist">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
</select>
```

I would like to print "player" 8 times on the form if I select 8 ; 7 if 7 ; 6 if 6...

Example:

```
player player player player player player player player
```

will be output if you select 8

Comment: What do you mean by `make 8 times "Player" on the form if i select 8`?

Comment: @yamboy "player 
player 
player 
player 
player 
player 
player 
player
"
You can correct if there is a better way to say it

Comment: @Mazeo check this https://jsfiddle.net/v06zdff5/ ?

Comment: @XYZ And i should make it in column with flexbox ?

Comment: @Mazeo Yes.And you and style it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code.Get the value of the select and  use for loop to display the text

```js
document.getElementById("playerlist").addEventListener("change", function() {

  var selected = this.value;
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "";
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < selected; i++) {
    html += '<div class="sub-text"> Player </div>';
  }
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = html;
});
```

```css
#text{
  
}
.sub-text{
   display:inline-block;
   padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<select id="playerlist" onchange="">
  <option value="0">Select Players</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
</select>

<div id="text">

</div>
```